# extjs viewport inside tabpanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, viewport, tabpanel

Good day, I am extjs newbie, I am using extjs 3, I had problem with my layout,I have the tabpanel and inside of the tab 1 will be the viewport, and the tab 2 is just a simple content, but when i click tab2, the viewport doesnt disappear, supposed to be the viewport is only at tab 1 or first tab. Below are my code, Please help, what if there is something wrong with my codes.

```
var Tabs;
var chatUi;
var content = "centerpanel";

var viewport1 = new Ext.Viewport({
    //id:       'chatUiLayout',
    layout: 'border',
    //renderTo :    'liveChatTextLiveHelp',
    items: [{
        width: 150,
        region: 'east',
        title: 'east'
    }, {
        region: 'center',
        title: 'center'
    }]
});


Tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
    id: 'liveChatTextLiveHelp',
    renderTo: 'div-live-chat',
    activeTab: 0,
    //region:       'center',
    //hieght:       200,
    plain: true,
    items: [{
        title: 'Live help',
        items: [ //viewport1  
        ],
        html: "<div id='" + content + "' class='90pers' ></div>"
    }, {
        title: 'Tab 2',
        html: "tab 2 content"
    }

    ],
    scope: this,
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function () {
            viewport1.render(content);
        },
        scope: this

    }

});
```

Answer (score 6):

Viewports are special containers that represent the entire browser window. They will always render themselves to the body, making them bad candidates for being inside something else. Instead of a viewport you should try a `panel` or `container` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a border layout inside tab 1, similar to [Windows with Layouts example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/window/layout.html).
Viewport cannot be hidden as it is bound to the browser window.